# C# If Equals Case insensitive

Tags: c#, if-statement, boolean, case

The following code will open up a Message Box containing the word "Fail".

**Is there a way to make the if statement case insensitive, so that the if statement passes and opens a mbox containg "Pass" without converting the character/string to upper/lower case?**

here is the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string one = "A";
        string two = "a";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (one == two)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Pass");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Fail");
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use this

```
string.Equals(one, two, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Your code would be

```
if (string.Equals(one, two, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
   MessageBox.Show("Pass");
}
else
{
   MessageBox.Show("Fail");
}
```

Using **CurrentCultureIgnoreCase** :

> Compare strings using culture-sensitive sort rules, the current
>   culture, and ignoring the case of the strings being compared.

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

```
if (string.Equals(one, two, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
```

From MSDN:

> [`StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.currentcultureignorecase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
>
> Gets a `StringComparer` object that performs **case-insensitive string comparisons** using the word comparison rules of the current culture.

Answer (score 1):

Various options:

```
if (String.Compare(one, two, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == 0) {
   // they are equal
}
```

Option 2:

```
if ((one ?? "").ToLower() == (two ?? "").ToLower())
   // they are equal
}
```

There are tons of other options, but these should get you started!

**NOTE** - One thing people regularly forget with string comparisons is null values. Be sure to watch for null values however you do your comparison. The second option I presented does an excellent job of this.

Answer (score 0):

Use a case insensitive string comparer:

```
if(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(one, two))
```

You should also consider if this comparison needs to be done in the user's culture.

Answer (score 0):

You should use .Equals() to compare strings. Then you can use StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase as the third argument to ignore case.

Answer (score 0):

You can as well use this

```
string one = "obi";
 string two = "Obi";

 if(one.Equals(two, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
   /* Your code */
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if(one.ToLower() == two.ToLower())
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: 1) this code doesn't compile. 2) it violates the premise of the question, which is bolded.

Comment: @ColinDeClue Oh sorry, I forgot the `()`'s. And calling ToLower will not change the actual variables, so if the OP were to use the variables later they would appear unchanged.